# Keyboard Module in python not working on mac

Tags: python

When ever I run

```
import keyboard if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    while True:
        print("bean") 
else:
    quit()
```

I get this error:

```
   Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 954, in _bootstrap_inner
```

Could someone please help could this possibly be the fact that im on a Mac or am I just dumb

Comment: Hi. Could you make sure that your code formatting is correct in your question? It will allow the community to more easily answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:

Your import and if should not be on the same line.
Import then begin if statement

Problem 2:

You have an infinite loop created by your
while True
with no exit. I think your intention is probably to print “bean” as long as q is pressed. If this is the case your if probably needs to be inside your while loop.

You are bound to have further problems after working those out but isn’t that point and enjoyment of programming?